# Laravel facebook authentication

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, authentication

I'm using the latest laravel 5.4 and socialite. Added all needed base on the instruction, routes, controller and redirection.

**Here's my problem:**

1. When click the ***signin using facebook button*** it throws an error saying:

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given, called in **my directory here**/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 294 and defined`

I know there's a lot of answers here but I tried every possible options but still not working.

Comment: dang, why screenshots?! post code as `code` -- well, could you share your `User` model?

Comment: thanks for reminding, im new to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `App\User` extends authenticable contract

```
<?php 
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

}
```

Comment: where do i put this? in the controller or user Model?

Comment: Thanks! it's working perfectly now...I already voted your answer.

Comment: No, my answer is not voted. Please vote again and mark it as the answer. Thank you

Comment: @EddyTheDoe it says my votes were recorded since I only have 11 reputation, all votes below 15 reputation will be recorded and evaluated.

Comment: But you can mark it as the answer first. regardless of your reputation.